# How to get days,hours,minutes,seconds left for an event with different timezone through mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My server has a timezone of US .Need to generate the JSON response from PHP for IST timings showing the days,hours,minutes,seconds left for some event.
I know it can be done using the PHP . I want to know if there is anyway to if I can get the same via mysql query like

I have an even in a table

```
EVENT - Diwali
event_date - 3 November 2013

and today is 22nd and 2:30 IST time.
```

If I make a query like below

```
select `events`, event_date from events_table where DAY(STR_TO_DATE(event_date, '%y-%m-%d')) >DAY(CURDATE())
```

how can get the days,hours,minutes with IST timezone?
Is this is achievable through query ?

**Solution**

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30');
```

Comment: There is [`CONVERT_TZ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function...

Comment: @CORRUPT I give `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-05-22 12:00:00','GMT','IST');` it output me `null` . Also how can I extract days,hours from this

Comment: Try something like `SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-05-22 12:00:00','-10:00', '+10:00');`. It returns valid date on success or `NULL` on failure.

Comment: @CORRUPT Thanks I use it and worked ! now If I want to replace `2013-05-22 12:00:00` with my current date and time ?

Comment: Try `CURDATE()` or `NOW()` instead of this. But I dont know how to format result... If you find answer, please post it here. Thanks.

Comment: Beautiful I have changed my code to `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30');` and it gives me desired output . Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `time_zone` on the mysql session before you execute the query:

```
SET time_zone = '+20:00';
```

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: I have updated the solution in main question and it worked !!

Comment: that's another way to do it :)